# Android ListView crashes the application

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, crash

I am trying to make a GUI in which I display 2 buttons on top followed by a list which increases as data is received.
previously, I was appending data in TextView but then I switched to ListView but thats crashing my application.

Here is my code:

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener 
{
    String[] packets;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button start =(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button stop =(Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(this);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,packets));

    }
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.start:
                         ((ArrayAdapter)getListAdapter()).add("hello");
            break;
       }
    }
}
```

My main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    > 
    <Button android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/stop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    />
   <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My list_item.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1630    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1646 
    ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 121   
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 936   
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3652    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 862  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 620 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

I want that when start is clicked hello gets added to the list.

I cant figure out what am I doing wrong, Please help.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace and/or logcat for this issue.

Comment: I have posted it, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `packets` is never initialized, so that is likely the cause of your exception.  You should at least declare it as an empty array with an initial capacity that makes sense for your application.  For example:

```
String[] packets = new String[10];
```

Also, you need to change the id of the ListView in your layout to:

```
@android:id/list
```

Comment: this doesnot help the problem, application still crashes.

Comment: I updated my answer with another issue I see in your code.  Give that a try. If it doesn't work, please add the exception message in addition to the stack trace.  Also, please describe in more detail when your application crashes.  For example. does it happen when you click a button or before the Activity is even displayed?

Comment: Its still not working, it crashes when the application starts.
There is no error/exception displayed in logcat but eclipse gives the above stacktrace. I have added list_item.xml .

Comment: Please post your manifest.xml.  Also, did you try looking for the exception in the LogCat window?  The message should be there.  Without more info, its hard to help.  My guess is that might have  typo in your manifest.xml where you specify MainActivity.

Comment: yea, it did try to find it out, but it displays nothing .
I have added AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I found out that setListAdapter is crashing application , if we comment it then application opens fine.